# Playing Sound at view change

Tags: ios, xcode, viewdidload

Im a newb. I have a audio sound playing as soon as the new view controller loads under viewdidload but now how would I drop that from memory to make it so if you go back to that view controller it would still play the audio again?

```
@implementation FFViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"crash",
                                              CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `viewWillAppear:` as it is called every time your is appeared.
Also check documentation for more methods that are called.
[Responding to View Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but I used the viewWillAppear and tried the viewdidappear, it will play the audio when the app starts but if i return to that screen no sound?